# iOS. How to pass touches to parent view of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, touch

I have a UIWebView that has `userInteractionEnabled=YES`.  It intercepts all touches and won't pass any touch to the parent view.  Is there any easy way to make it pass touches to parent view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found [this article](http://wyldco.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/), which says:

> There are different ways to capture touches over a Web View. One would be to extend the UIWebView class, but Apple says you should not, so we will stay away from that solution in case it causes problem later. Instead, we are going to extend the UIWindow class, and capture touch events before they get propagated to the correct view(s).

it continues to describe how this is done with sample code.  see http://wyldco.com/blog/2010/11/how-to-capture-touches-over-a-uiwebview/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do that**

```
- (void) touchesBegan: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

    //call your parent controller touchesBegan
    [parent touchesBegan: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {

        //call your parent controller touchesMoved
        [parent touchesMoved: touches withEvent: event];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //call your parent controller touchesEnded
    [parent touchesEnded: touches withEvent: event];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. It seems that the UIWebView cannot be subclassed.